# Rails: send a 401 error without rendering a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unauthorized

I'm trying to send a 401 authorized from a Rails controller for webhooks, but I can't seem to the right way to do it since I'm not rendering a page.

```
render plain: "Unauthorized", status: :unauthorized
```

throws this error:

```
Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for [:error, "Unauthorized"]:Array>
```

I don't understand why because

```
render plain: "Unauthorized", status: 400
```

works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
head(:unauthorized)
```

Returns a response that has no content (merely a status code and headers).

See [ActionController::Head](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head).

Comment: I've tried that as well and I'm still getting error the same `Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'bytesize' for [:error, "Unauthorized"]:Array>` Is there something else that needs to go with this to make an unauthorized response?

Comment: That's sounds more like an error on the other side where the response is being consumed and is not answerable without that code.

Comment: On the other side I'm just using Postman to test it out.

Comment: Strange, do you have any middleware that could explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you, by any chance, using [this snippet](https://github.com/wardencommunity/rails_warden#usage) from `rails_warden` or equivalent middleware?

If so, the correct stanza is

```rb
  manager.failure_app = Proc.new { |_env|
    ['401', {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [{ error: 'Unauthorized' }.to_json]]
  }
```

Comment: In case someone wants to pass response you sent in controller:


``` 
  ['401', {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [_env['action_controller.instance'].response.body]]
```